# Can't type props of MUI Button

Tags: typescript, material-ui

```
import * as React from "react";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import MuiButton from "@mui/material/Button";
import Slider from "@mui/material/Slider";

interface Props {
  type: "primary" | "secondary";
}

export const MySlider = styled(Slider)<Props>(
  (props) => `
  color: ${props.type === "primary" ? "red" : "blue"};
`
);

export const MyButton = styled(MuiButton)<Props>(
  (props) => `
  color: ${props.type === "primary" ? "green" : "gold"};
`
);

export default function App() {
  return <MyButton type="primary">hello</MyButton>;
}
```

`props` is getting typed properly for the Slider component, but `props` gets typed to `never` for the Button component - anyone knows why?

https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-bose-xtx52q?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**type** - is a reserved attribute for a button element, you are trying to override the type, therefore throws type error. If you will change key of interface **typeprops** (or other name) instead of **type** error will be gone.

[image]

##### Component

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import MuiButton from "@mui/material/Button";
import Slider from "@mui/material/Slider";

interface Props {
  typeprops: "primary" | "secondary";
}

export const MySlider = styled(Slider)<Props>(
  (props) => `
  color: ${props.typeprops === "primary" ? "red" : "blue"};
`
);

export const MyButton = styled(MuiButton)<Props>(
  (props) => `
  color: ${props.typeprops === "primary" ? "green" : "gold"};
`
);

export default function App() {
  return <MyButton typeprops="primary">hello</MyButton>;
}
```

[image: Edit dazziling-code]